# Error installing Oracle Enterprise Pack for Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I'm trying to install OEPE from the site:

http://download.oracle.com/otn_software/oepe/ganymede

But I get the following error:

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: Oracle Common Tools 1.1.1.200904131333 (com.oracle.tools.eclipse.ganymede.common.feature.feature.group 1.1.1.200904131333)
  Missing requirement: Oracle Common Tools 1.0.1.200904131333 (oracle.eclipse.tools.common 1.0.1.200904131333) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.jdt.core [3.4.2,3.5.0)' but it could not be found
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Oracle Common Tools 1.1.1.200904131333 (com.oracle.tools.eclipse.ganymede.common.feature.feature.group 1.1.1.200904131333)
    To: oracle.eclipse.tools.common [1.0.1.200904131333]
```

Version information:

```
Eclipse Java Development Tools

Version: 3.5.0.v20090527-2000-7r88FEeFJePyvYeA33DjZ_c1
Build id: I20090611-1540
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the error:

> requires 'bundle org.eclipse.jdt.core [3.4.2,3.5.0)'

This means 3.4.2 inclusive to 3.5.0 exclusive, so it appears the version of the Oracle plugin will not work with Eclipse 3.5, try it with a 3.4 version of Eclipse (from 3.4.2 onwards).

Answer (score 1):

You have a version for Eclipse 3.4.

Oracle also has a [technology preview](http://www.oracle.com/technology/software/products/oepe/oepe_11g.html) for 3.5 that you could try instead.

Comment: I just noticed that as well, but also it requires older versions than what's included with the latest Eclipse:

'bundle org.eclipse.jpt.utility [1.3.0,1.4.0]'